# OSIRIS-REx engines location

Tags: engines

I'm trying to locate all the OSIRIS-REx engines.

Here: http://spaceflight101.com/osiris-rex/osiris-rex-spacecraft-overview/ (Propulsion System) I read that there are: 4 x 275 N, 6 x 22 N, 16 x 4.5 N and 2 x 80 mN.
My biggest doubt is about the four 275 N engines.

I'm using the 3D models found here: https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/osirisrex-2013-comp, https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2360/osiris-rex-3d-model/ and https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/osiris-rex-4502d7705147439eab474902fa283c89.
All the models show the 6-engine group, but I don't see the 4 main engines.

**Where are the 4 main engines?**

Re-asked question: [Where are the 6 22-N OSIRIS-REx engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38113/20397)

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

Here https://mk0spaceflightnoa02a.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/10.jpg we see 4 main engines. I thought that the spaceflight101.com image was an outdated preliminary image, but it seems that that image is correct and that the 3D models are wrong.

Then I need to change the question: **where are the 6 22-N engines?**

Comment: Since your original question was answered, it seems a bit unfair to change it to invalidate the answer. Why not accept the answer and ask a new one?

Comment: @Organic Marble done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second image on your link http://spaceflight101.com/osiris-rex/osiris-rex-spacecraft-overview/  has an element labelled "200 N Thrusters" near the bottom of the image.

[image]

The section of that same document that starts "OSIRIS-REx is equipped with four Aerojet Rocketdyne MR-107S thrusters..." has a picture of that thruster and describes them as "installed in a single bank on the base of the spacecraft".

So I think that's them.

Comment: I've added the image to make reading the answer more convenient...

Comment: The spaceflight101 article linked says there are 4 thrusters, then says “with the 6 engines at nominal thrust...”. The 3D models seem to show six thrusters at that position. I wonder if the design switched between four and six thrusters at some point.

Comment: It seems that the final design is 4 engines, as shown in this photo: https://mk0spaceflightnoa02a.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/10.jpg.