# Where are the 6 22-N OSIRIS-REx engines?

Tags: engines, osiris-rex

Does anyone could link an image/3D model/photo that shows the 6 22-N engines?

Related question: [OSIRIS-REx engines location](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38093/20397).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://spaceflight101.com/osiris-rex/osiris-rex-spacecraft-overview/) shows a picture of the whole OSIRIS-REx spacecraft and also shows an individual picture of the thruster.

[image]

[image: MR-106L thruster manufactured by Aerojet Rocketdyne.]

The name of this engine is the [MR-106L thruster](https://www.rocket.com/space/space-power-propulsion/monopropellant-rocket-engines) and it  uses Hydrazine Monopropellant fuel and has a specific impulse of 229 - 235 seconds. These engines are used to control the pitch and yaw during the main engine burn.

Here is an [interactive 3D-model of OSIRIS-REx](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/osiris-rex-4502d7705147439eab474902fa283c89) which you can use to locate the 6 thrusters. The 6 main 200 N thrusters are located at the bottom of the spacecraft, where the diagram above shows it. However, they have changed it to four main engines. All these 3-D models are outdated. The small six 22 N thrusters are located in the "rectangular area" beside the cluster of the main engines. There are 2 of these "rectangles". They don't look like thrusters in this model but it does in [this Wikipedia model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSIRIS-REx#/media/File:OSIRIS-REx.stl).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good! But could you indicate where they are located?

Comment: @Cristiano Just made an edit that shows a 3D-model of the spacecraft.

Comment: That model seems wrong because there is a photo that shows 4 engines: https://mk0spaceflightnoa02a.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/10.jpg

Comment: The only way to solve the enigma is to show both the 4-engine main group and the 6 22-N thrusters. Can you locate the 4 main engines in the 3D model (please, take a look at my other question: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38093/20397).

Comment: @Cristiano You are right, there are 4 engines. I also think I might've located those 6 22 N thrusters.

Comment: Their off-axis location seems a bit strange to me, but I think you're right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cristiano They're only there to control its pitch and yaw.

Comment: I think that they are also used for the very small DV corrections during the Orbital-A phase and probably also for the entry/exit maneuvers to/from Orbital-C/B; I'm investigating with the help of the NAIF data files...